# Is there any limit on number of ElasticSearch Indicies?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are planning to have a separate index per day (currently we have one per month), wondering if there is any limit on the number of ES Indicies and how the search performance will be effected?

Comment: for the ELk (ES, Logstash, Kibana) there is also one new index per day created. So I guess there is no real problem, but I dont know if there is some exact number hardcoded for a limit. So far I can just say over 200 is no problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are also using a high amount of indices in our production environment.
So far i can tell you that it works smoothly and there is no real drawback, but u have to consider that every single index comes with some minor memory overhead.
Generally the limit of indices is provided by your backing hardware, cause elastic has to load more data into memory etc.  So the only limit is your hardware! I recommend reading [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html) also.